Wordpress. Contact Form 7. How to add several attachments in email using code?
Trying to add attachments to the letter.
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'custom_attach_files_to_email');
function custom_attach_files_to_email($contact_form) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ($submission) {
        $uploaded_files = $submission->uploaded_files();
        $attachments = array();
        
        foreach ($uploaded_files as $uploaded_file) {
            $attachments[] = $uploaded_file;
        }
        
        $attachments[] = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/files/file.txt';
        //$attachments[] = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/files/file_2.txt';
        
        $mail = $contact_form->prop('mail');
        $mail['attachments'] = implode(',', $attachments);
        $contact_form->set_properties(array('mail' => $mail));
    }
}

This works only for ONE file. When i try to send two files (file.txt and file_2.txt) - the letter has no files at all
I need to send several files using code.

add more test files in form configuration to see how this is managed in the code : https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/

so, this code sends a letter with files.
it's very important to set the correct path to file and files shouldn't be empty. also this code removes all attached files before (i didn't find no more ways)
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'custom_attach_files_to_email');
function custom_attach_files_to_email($contact_form) {
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
if ($submission) {
    $mail = $contact_form->prop('mail');
    
    $f_1 = '/CORRECT_path_to_file/';
    $f_2 = '/CORRECT_path_to_file/';

    $mail['attachments'] = "
        $f_1
        $f_2
    ";
        
    $contact_form->set_properties(array('mail' => $mail));
}

}
